# Can not flash LK2.08 for original firmwares on my spica

Tags: kernel, samsung-galaxy-spica

Can not flash LK2.08 for original firmwares. I try like this: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/root-samsung-galaxy-spica-i5700-with-leshaks-kernel/

i am using this kernel: http://forum.samdroid.net/f55/lk2-08-original-firmwares-root-new-superuser-wifi-tether-bb-12-07-2010-a-1193/

and i copy it to my localh computer hard disk not to phone SD card.

Whn i click start i get this:

```
> Download Start... <0> Create File...
> <1> StartThread Detected : 1 <2>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <3>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <4>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <5>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <6>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <7>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <8>
> StartThread Detected : 0 <1> setup
> connection...
```

but takes 20 minutes and nothing changed. Is this normal or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close Odin, disconnect your phone, restart Odin, reboot your phone, put the phone into Download mode again, and then connect your phone and ensure Odin sees it.  Sometimes Odin just doesn't recognize the device and you need to try again.  Odin will show something like the yellow highlighted area below when the phone is properly connected:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: thx but problem was with PDA. i need to clear it first. But thx.